# Stuck on upload & download with iCloud Drive on Sonoma

Tags: macos, icloud

I accidentally turned on the Desktop & Document Folder in the iCloud Drive settings, and I don't understand how iCloud Drive synchronization works. However, I tried to retrieve the files I accidentally moved between folders, and it seems like the processes are still running. Currently, I have tried using the command `killall bird && rm -rf CloudDocs` for the path `~/Library/Application\ Support`, but the upload & download processes do not stop and continue there. The clearest example is in the image below where I don't have a close button to completely stop these processes. How should I handle this? Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't tell from your question what the actual problem is you're trying to solve?  Is it that you want to turn off the synchronization process?

Comment: @fsb as the above mentions, I just want to kill 2 processes on the image, but it dont show me any button to close T.T

Comment: I get that, I'm asking why you want to do this?  What problem is it causing you having those two processes run?  Have you tried restarting to see if that kills them?

Comment: yes, I tried to restart many times, but I still cannot solve the problem